# How to run a javascript function before starting any test case in Protactor?

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

Actually, i am writing some test cases for one angular app but the first page is taking too much time too load and having a popup box for instruction. So i need to store some value in localStorage of browser for making that popup box invisible. So how can i run any javascript function before running any test case?

Comment: please don't suggest for beforeEach() function because i already tried that one but that's not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, protractor is syncing with angular, which makes it wait for $http or $timeout you can check if that's the case on this particular page with this: [Canonical way to debug Protractor-to-Angular sync issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865376/canonical-way-to-debug-protractor-to-angular-sync-issues/42916230#42916230)

or you can inject the behaviour with mocked module

#### protractor.config.js

```
onPrepare: function() {
    var doTheFuncyStuff= function() {
        angular
            .module('doTheFuncyStuff', [])
            .run([function(){
              //do something here so the popup isn't displayed
              window.localStorage.setItem('my-var', 'my-val');
            }]);
    };

    browser.addMockModule('doTheFuncyStuff', doTheFuncyStuff);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply buddy. Now i tried your provided solution but i need to use browser inside .run. So how can i use browser inside browser?

Comment: i need to run browser.executeScript() inside .run method

Comment: You can run any code in the `run` block, whatever you put in executeScript you can do it there too

Comment: but it is throwing the error when i am trying to access browser inside run

`browser.executeScript("window.localStorage.setItem('my-var', 'my-val');");`

Comment: I've edited my answer, you just need to skip the `browser.executeScript` since the mocked module will run in browser, everything else runs in protractor instance