# How to wait for URL to load after button click in protractor?

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, end-to-end

I'm doing an end-to-end testing using protractor on an angular 2 project and i'm required to test a login operation. The problem here is that when login button is clicked the expect statement still gets the login page's URL as supposed to home page. If I wait, then the test succeeds. I have read somewhere in the documentation that protractor waits for processes to complete automatically, so,

1. What is causing this error?
2. How can I perform the operation correctly without explicitly using `wait()` method?
3. Does protractor have something similar to `fakeAsync`, `async` or atleast `whenStable` like in unit
   test?

Here's my test case

```
it("User successfully login",()=>{
    browser.get(browser.baseUrl + '/account/login').then(() => {
        return expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(browser.baseUrl +  "/account/login")
    }).then(()=>{
        element(by.tagName('input[type=text]')).sendKeys('username');
        element(by.tagName('input[type=password]')).sendKeys('password');
        element(by.css('button[type=submit]')).click().then(()=>{
            return expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(browser.baseUrl + "/home");
        });

    });
});
```

**Note:**

1. I have instructions to avoid using `browser.wait()` method.
2. Login button sends an http request to the backend via API.

#### Workaround solution [Based on Ernst's solution]:

I sort of solved this problem. I don't know if it works for other scenarios or if it's the correct approach. I added

```
browser.wait(EC.urlContains(browser.baseUrl + "/account/login"), 10000);
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.wait(EC.urlContains(browser.baseUrl + "/home");
```

just after click() event and it seems to work for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What causes the error:**

`click()` returns a promise, which protractor waits to be resolved. It is probably resolved the moment, when the login-request got sent to the server and not when the homepage is loaded. Therefore the execution of the next step starts before the page is loaded.

**Why not `wait()`:**

I'm not sure, on what base you got the instruction not to use `browser.wait()`. Most probably you shouldn't use `browser.sleep()` (because that command is always obsolete), but if you don't want to use `browser.wait()` your developers may not once leave the initially opened Angular Page.

**`fakeAsync`, `whenStable` and more:**

Protractor uses `whenStable` by default within `browser.waitForAngular()`, which is always called after a promise and as long as you didn't switch off `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`... which you only need to switch off for non-angular pages or if your developers use i.e. long lasting Macrotasks, that would lead to timeouts.

Further because the Selenium Control Flow will get deprecated in probably November 2018 ([read about here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969)), there is `async/await` available.
[Read this important guide here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) and also some [further infos from protractor about it here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md)

**Now in your case:**

You don't need to use `then()`s in your case, as you don't need to resolve the promise immediately. `expect()` will automatically resolve your promise, so there is no need for a `then()` there.

In fact Protractor executes all commands line by line as if they were all wrapped within `then()`s, so it automatically keeps your execution synchronous (as long as you don't start an async task by using `then()` in the code.

So here my suggestion for your code:

```
it("User successfully login",()=>{
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;  //or within onPrepare() of conf.js put global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions ... to make it everywhere available.
    browser.get(browser.baseUrl + '/account/login');
    //next line lets protractor wait max 5 seconds for your url to become, what you want.
    browser.wait(EC.urlContains(browser.baseUrl +  "/account/login"), 5000);
    //additionally after the URL appeared, use this command to wait until the page is fully loaded.
    browser.waitForAngular();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(browser.baseUrl +  "/account/login");
    element(by.tagName('input[type=text]')).sendKeys('username');
    element(by.tagName('input[type=password]')).sendKeys('password');
    element(by.css('button[type=submit]')).click();
    //next line lets protractor wait max 5 seconds for your url to become, what you want.
    //as here a new page is loaded and the click()-promise is resolved before, use this:
    browser.wait(EC.urlContains(browser.baseUrl +  "/account/login"), 5000);
    //additionally after the URL appeared, use this command to wait until the page is fully loaded.
    browser.waitForAngular();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(browser.baseUrl + "/home");
});
```

If you get now timeouts, then that is a separate issue to debug.
Check [this Protractor site for infos about timeouts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md) and check [this SO-Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46608556/8683679) for how to debug timeouts.

Comment: Still the result is not consistent...It succeeds or fails sometimes. I tried to increase the wait interval. But the results are same

Comment: In this case use both wait's together. First wait for the URL to be correct, then let Protractor wait until all promises are resolved. So use both lines `browser.wait(EC.urlContains(browser.baseUrl +  "/account/login"), 5000);  browser.waitForAngular();` ... evtl. after both of the `browser.get()` commands

Comment: Now the test keeps on waiting. It doesn't stop.

Comment: as `browser.waitForAngular()` just uses `whenStable`, this means the page is not yet stable. Reason could be a continuously polling `$timeout` or if Angular is used (not AngularJS) it could be a Macrotask.
I added links to find information about timeouts and how to debug them.

Comment: I have posted the workaround based on your solution. Suggest changes if you find any. Thank you! Great explanation by the way!

Comment: Correction: the .then() was redundant, but not a problem. Execution is still synchronous because WebDriver has a modified promise manager integrated with the control flow. See section "ManagedPromise Integration" in the [selenium-webdriver promise docu](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.html)