# Protractor and headless chrome: Could not find Angular on page

Tags: angular, protractor

I can run my e2e test on my Angular2 app with chrome and it works just fine. When I try to use headless chrome with just the additional chromeOptions it fails to find the angular app. I've tried with directConnect:true and also starting the selenium server with webdriver-manager first but both fail the same.

The first thing the test does is call browser().get('/');

yarn run v1.3.2
$ protractor protractor.conf.js
[10:51:34] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[10:51:34] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
 
Jasmine started
[10:51:48] E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page https://localhost:4200/ : retries looking for angular exceeded

Here's my versions
Node Version: 6.11.0
Protractor Version: 5.2.0
Angular Version: 1.4.4
Browser(s): chrome headless
Operating System and Version Windows 7

This is my protractor.conf.js

```
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600"]
    }
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'https://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
   defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function () { }
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      spec: { displayStacktrace: true }
    }));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
      savePath: './protractor-results/e2e'
    }));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running into the chrome sandbox security error.  Add `--no-sandbox` as a Chrome option as below in your protractor config file and it will hopefully work.  :-)

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: ["./e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts"],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: "chrome",
    chromeOptions: {
      binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN,
      args: ['--no-sandbox']
    }
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you check this [Issue on Protractor here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4564) and [this Chrome-Bug here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2105)?

Did you check, if there is angular present on the page?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46608556/8683679) to know, what to look after. Basically check, if your browser console returns anything on either `window.angular.version` (AngularJS) or `window.getAllAngularRootElements` (Angular).

If one of the two returns results, but your tests still don't work, I'd suggest to open an [Issue on Protractor Github](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues).