# Error:Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

I am new for Protractor and writing a code.
when I ran my code my desired actions are performed with an error

`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`

And my test was failed due to this.

I have applied timeout command to handle

```
import 'jasmine'; 
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL= 50000;
```

however same message is coming every time and my test is failing.

Comment: [Research here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts)

Comment: Hi  have Tried putting timeout command in my config file.

 jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 9000000
  },
and i my script also used 
browser.driver.sleep(10000)

but facing same error. Please suggest me the any solution for his

Comment: please update your question with the test-spec you're executing, when you get the timeout. It's either a problem of your spec-code or of the page under test. Extending the timeout almost never is the solution. ... more likely it's a code issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your timeout command in your config file like this.

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 600000
  }

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, however i have used such timeout command in my config file  
 jasmineNodeOpts: { defaultTimeoutInterval: 90000},

Comment: Is your script throwing this error at the mid or at the start itself?

Comment: yes i have
browser.driver.sleep(10000);

but still facing same error.

Comment: The issue is with your webpage and that is not due to your script. May be your server is down.

Comment: Try giving browser.wait command instead of browser.sleep since browser.wait involves promise.

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably related to the page you're testing.

- [See an earlier SO-Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46608556/8683679) for how to debug along such timeouts.
- [See Protractors timeout-page](http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts)

Update your question with additional information, if you couldn't find your answer in above two links.