# Protractor works with Angular JS fails with Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, automated-tests

There are 2 different sections of the application to automate: the admin section (built using AngularJS) and the EndUser section (built using Angular 5)

The admin section is working as expected but the for the Angular 5 section we need to set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` to get tests working.

Here is the conf.js and spec.js file. Help would be greatly appreciated

**Conf.js:**

```
exports.config = {

    // The address of a running selenium server.
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['C:\\Users\\gjreddy\\Desktop\\Shubha\\Protractor\\Specs\\Scripts\\createStore.js'],
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },
    allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
}
```

Comment: You may have forgotten to include your spec.js file

Comment: Can you check out this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588749/how-to-debug-timed-out-waiting-for-asynchronous-angular-tasks-failure-to-find-e). It goes over some of the reasons why angular can have an issue syncing on certain pages